# How to implement an EventListener for a JSlider. I want it to trigger when i hold / click the left mouse on the Slider-Knob

Tags: java, swing, event-listener, jslider

I have a `JPasswordField` with a hidden Password. Now when I click the Knob of the `JSlider` and/or hold it - I want to unhide the content of the `JPasswordField`. The mechanism to unhide and hide it again is already implemented but I need help or an advice how to detect a click and/or left mouse-button-hold on the `JSlider`-Knob. I only found an `EventListener` for a changing value of the slider but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Why not use a JButton for unhiding / hiding the  password?

Comment: A `JSlider` is definitely an interesting choice of component for this use case. Nonetheless, as for any component, you can add a `MouseListener`, listening for the `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` events.